# Node.js googlemaps cluster execute error

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, google-maps

I'm now use the node.js platform. And I want to use googlemap cluster library. However I can't execute the source code.

googlemaps cluster api url : https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer

This library's index is below.

- dosc
- examples
- images
- src
- etc..

In the directory of examples, I want to test a "simple_example.html".

My node.js source code is below.

[app.js]

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.set('view engine','ejs');
var path = require("path");
app.set("public", path.join(__dirname, "public"));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render("simple_example", {} )
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Running at Port 3000");
```

[simple_example.ejs] (important script part)

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="public/data.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>

<script>
  function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,
          dataPhoto.longitude);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'public/images/m'});
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

[image]

This picture is result of execute by my source code. but the picture doesn't have markered in the map. I expected picture is below.

[image]

I tried path change of src, change web platform(as python) but I can't solve the problem. Who know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you create a marker cluster, support it by using [`addMarker()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#add) method or by providing a array of markers to the constructor.

When they say add marker to constructor by providing a array of markers it's similar to doing this:

```
var markers = []; //create a global array where you store your markers
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.photos[i].latitude,
data.photos[i].longitude);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': latLng});
markers.push(marker); //push individual marker onto global array
}
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers); //create clusterer and push the global array of markers into it.
```

To add it using addMarker() you basically add it to the cluster like the following:

```
var markerCluster //cluster object created on global scope

//do your marker creation and add it like this:
markerCluster.addMarker(newMarker, true); //if specify true it'll redraw the map
```

Here's a reference to MarkerCluster: https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/examples.html

Also, here's a demo app how to use markercluster: https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer

Comment: Sorry, I cant understand it..):